# Cant drag form widgets on my layout in android studio

Tags: android, forms

I start to learn android .  I noticed that my form widgets doesn't work I cant drag it to my layout. How to fix it ? or is it a bug .

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the answer @ [Android Studio - Cannot Drag and Drop Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277750/android-studio-cannot-drag-and-drop-button) helped me solve it.

In short, you can't drag widgets into `activity_main.xml`. So make a new file called `content_main.xml`, and then add the line:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

to your `activity_main.xml` file. Then you can drag items into the `content_main.xml` file, and they will appear in your `activity_main.xml` layout. Hope that helps!