# Android Studio - Cannot Drag and Drop Button

Tags: android

I just created a new project, blank activity. If I go into the interface for the activity_main.xml I cannot drag and drop any widgets. I tried changing the theme, still nothing. Here is my activity_main.xml and manifest files.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio changed the layout `activity_main.xml` and made it as a container for things like `FloatingActionButton`, `ToolBar`.. so you can't drag and drop buttons there. They created another xml file called `content_main.xml` where you can add all your other views. They include the content_main inside activity_main by

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Comment: @reddead You're not alone, I too had the same problem :D

Comment: how is this specified programmatically? It seems like I should still be able to create a new activity, drag and drop my views, and then specify it as the main acitivity afterwards.

Comment: @robertotomás You should put your views in `content_main.xml` and don't worry, it's included in the `activity_main.xml` and you won't face any problems

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that adding something programmatically to the xml file (click "text" button on the bottom left) then made it so the ui worked... but only after I added something programmatically.

Comment: great, I hav tried all solutions, and finally your solution was the perfect one.